# Passing client-side JSON to dataTable - syntax?

Tags: json, datatables, client-side

I'm stuck trying to  pass JSON to a dataTable.

I load JSON at a different point in the script, then truncate the part I need and pass it into a function that is supposed to render the table. 
The function is:

```
    function populateCasesTable(d){
        var json = d.cases;
        var cols = [
            {  "data"   :  json.service_area},
            {  "data"   :  json.presenting_issue },
            {  "data"   :  json.referred_by },
            {  "data"   :  json.date_opened },
            {  "data"   :  json.case_status },
            {  "data"   :  json.preferred_staff }
        ];

        console.log(json);

        $('#cases_table').DataTable( {
           "data": json,
           "columns": cols
        } );
    }
```

HTML for the table is

```
<table  id='cases_table' width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Service Area</th>
        <th>Presenting Issue</th>
        <th>Referred by</th>
        <th>Date opened</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Preferred Staff</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

The console.log output returns the right amount of objects (12) and a single object looks eg:

```
    0 Object: 
    action:9
    case_status:"Open"
    date_created:"11/07/2017"
    date_opened:"11/07/2017"
    file:5
    id:31646
    issues:8
    preferred_staff:"Doc Kuran"
    presenting_issue:"Anxiety Disorder"
    referral:0
    referred_by:"Academic staff"
    serviceAreaId:14
    service_area:"Disability Services"
    staff:0
```

I get the right number of pages rendered accompanied by the cryptic 'DataTables warning: table id=cases_table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4' pop-up.

I'm sure this is a config issue, but I could not work this out.

What  am  I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Cols must be set as follows:

```
 var cols = [
            {  "data"   :  'service_area'},
            {  "data"   :  'presenting_issue' },
            {  "data"   :  'referred_by' },
            {  "data"   : 'date_opened' },
            {  "data"   : 'case_status' },
            {  "data"   : 'preferred_staff' }
        ];
```